# To show arraylist data in specific format

Tags: html, jsp, arraylist

I am getting request attribute on a JSP page like = `ArrayList arr= [a,b,c[e,f,g[j,k,l]]]`.  The list can be long. How should I show it in such a way a,b,c is parent of e,f,g is parent of j,k,l?

I want something like this or better

```
<tr onclick=showchild()>
<td> a </td> <td> b </td> <td> c </td>
</tr>
```

When I click on above `tr` its child i.e, below `tr` should be shown.

```
< tr onclick=showchild()>
<td> e </td  <td> f </td>  <td> g </td> 
</tr>
```

Comment: 1°) There's no question. 2°) Even if there were a hidden question, it is really un-understandable. So first, edit your question to make it more intelligible, and then, show what you already tried yet to solve your problem.

Comment: its a kind of tree i want to show I have to iterate the whole arraylist and i have to fit them in a stucture

Comment: Please tell me if its not clear yet

Comment: It's not clear yet. What's the actual question? What works? What doesn't?